# E-mail is not forwarding by using php mail function if sender and receiver are from same domain

Tags: php, function, email, dns

I am trying to send mail by using php `mail()` function. The code is in `imi-k.edu.in` domain. 
If using the following code:

```
mail("srimanta12@gmail.com","Test Mail","Cool message","From:srimanta@imi-k.edu.in");
```

The mail is firing to `srimanta12@gmail.com` account.
But if I use:

```
mail("srimanta@imi-k.edu.in","Test Mail","Cool message","From:srimanta@imi-k.edu.in");
```

Then mail is not firing.
I am using `godaddy` server.
Is this due to the same sender, receiver and domain account?
Please let me know the reason of the issue. It is a very critical issue as this code is on live server.

Error after using phpmailer library

```
2015-11-02 09:46:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO imi-k.edu.in 2015-11-02 09:46:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2015-11-02 09:46:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO imi-k.edu.in 2015-11-02 09:46:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 2015-11-02 09:46:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 2015-11-02 09:49:24 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550-Verification failed for 550-No Such User Here" 550 Sender verify failed 2015-11-02 09:49:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-11-02 09:49:24 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 421 ip-104-238-95-235.secureserver.net: SMTP command timeout - closing connection 2015-11-02 09:49:24 SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: srimanta.chakraborty@viavitae.co.in Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: srimanta.chakraborty@viavitae.co.in
```

Comment: use phpmailer library

Comment: using phpmailer , I am getting error which is mentioned in the question part.